# how to call using the rest_client in codeigniter

Tags: rest, codeigniter, curl

I am new to CodeIgniter and Rest API. I am trying to implement REST API in CodeIgniter and have used Phil Sturgeon's rest-client and rest-server. I have watched few tutorials and have successfully implemented the Rest-Server part (checking with Chrome's Rest Client APP). But, to implement the Rest-Client, I am having few troubles.

Do I need to have cURL and CodeIgniter's cUrl Library?
If yes, how should I set it up?

[I watched this tutorial too by Phil Sturgeon](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/working-with-restful-services-in-codeigniter--net-8814) but in this tutorial, he has only used the Rest-Client function to call the Server. But not defined where to put it. Here's the code

```
function rest_client($id){
    $this->load->library('rest', array(
        'server' => 'http://localhost/rest/index.php/restgetcontroller/',

    ));

    $user = $this->rest->get('user', array('id' => $id), 'json');

    echo $user->name;
}
```

I am sorry if it is too simple.

Thank You

Edit: I made a **Client** controller and put there a method to call it. But when I load the page, I get this error.

```
Call to undefined method CI_Loader::spark()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use wherever you need to retrieve a value from your API.

`$user` will have a value you can use for your purpose.

Basically, you would use the API where you used to use a Model, because now the interaction with the database is made with the API, not from your Controllers directly.

Answer (score 0):

To call RESTful APIs you'll require CURL, there's a library called `Guzzlehttp` to use CURL more efficiently.

You can use `composer` to install the library or simply download the zip and require it in your controller.

Example Usage:

```
    try {
        $guzzleHttp = new GuzzleHttp\Client([
            'verify' => false
        ]);

        $http_response = $guzzleHttp->request('GET', 'http://localhost/rest/index.php/restgetcontroller/');
        $response = json_decode($http_response->getBody()->getContents());

        return $data;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        log_message('error', $e->getMessage());
        return false;
    }
```